# Is it true that the dimension of an eigenspace of a square matrix is at most the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By "the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue", I mean the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=\det(xI-A)$, i. e. the maximum integer $k$ such that $(x-\lambda)^k$ divides $p(x)$.
I believe that this is true, but I failed to find a proof.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

**Hint**:

To see this, take a basis of $E_\lambda(A)$ (the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix $A$) and expand it in a basis of the vector space $E=\Bbb R^n$. Using the matrix of $A$ in this basis and the fact that the characteristic polynomial is the same as in the previous basis, you find that $p(x)=(\lambda I_n -x)^{\dim{E_\lambda(A)}}Q(x)$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial. So, by definition of the multiplicity of a root, you get $\dim{E_\lambda(A)} \le$ the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root of $p$.